# Use of uninitialized value in die... (perl)

Tags: perl, die

When I run my script, I get the error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in die at /usr/local/bin/tacms/subscriptionScheduler.pl line 101.
Died at /usr/local/bin/tacms/subscriptionScheduler.pl line 101.
```

Line 101 is the line that reads:

```
$contentRow = $contentSth->fetchrow_hashref() or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Just as a clarification, this error comes on when I change the keywords. If I use my testing keywords `VERSETEST AND QUOTETEST`, I don't get this error. But when I use keywords `VERSE and QUOTE`, then I encounter this error.

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: There is too little information in the question to answer it properly. Enable [tracing](http://p3rl.org/DBI#TRACING) to show the generated SQL, then [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11078829/edit) to include the new info.

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly normal for [`fetchrow_hashref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#fetchrow_hashref) to return `undef` when there are no more rows to return.  Since `$dbh->errstr` is returning `undef` also, that must be what happened.

This is why I usually set the [`RaiseError`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#RaiseError) attribute to true, so that I don't have to check for errors after every single call to DBI.  That way, I know that when `fetchrow_hashref` returns `undef` it indicates the end of the results and not an error.

If you don't use `RaiseError`, you can check for an error as follows:

```
unless ($contentRow = $contentSth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
  die $dbh->errstr if defined($contentSth->err);
  print "No more results\n"; # if we get here
}
```

Comment: @ikegami, your example was completely broken.  I've fixed it.  (Aside from using `$sth` instead of `$contentSth`, `err` is defined if there _was_ an error, not if there wasn't one.)